# Laravel Homestead (Windows) how to add vendor to PATH

Tags: laravel, vagrant, homestead

I've set up my Homestead and i am able to connect via vagrant ssh.
I also add Laravel installer over Composer via `composer global require laravel/installer`.
But know, i don't know how to make it work cause in the vagrant user folder, there is no `.composer/vendor` folder. i figured out that the composer has installed the vendor folder under `/root/.composer` but when i try to access, i don't have permission cause it's in root folder.

My goal is to use the Laravel installer. For that, i need to add the path to the $PATH. Here the guideline from the docu:

> Make sure to place the $HOME/.composer/vendor/bin directory (or the equivalent directory for your OS) in your $PATH so the laravel executable can be located by your system

But i can't do that in vagrant or at least i don't know how.

And yes, i know that composer is installed, that part worked.

So how can i make it work?

Comment: could you please be more specific what are you trying to do?  you want to access /root directory or you want to add vendor? do you want to add local vendor or global one?

Comment: Composer is already installed in homestead. Via vagrant ssh you can run composer commands.

Comment: i edited my question

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it.
For all others with the same issue: i need to run as administrator and i also had an outdated vagrantbox